# PHP submit to self FAILING

Tags: php

** SOLVED: submit to self now working.**

My simple html/php (bootstrap) form refuses to submit to self. Can you see anything wrong with my code? I've tried the obvious $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and a number of other failures. Out of ideas.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
             <h2>Contact us!</h2>

<!-- changed this           
<form name="enquiryform" method="post" action="">
<form class="form-horizontal">
-->

<!-- to this: --> <form class="form-horizontal" name="enquiryform" method="post" action="">

            <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="first_name">Name *</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First name" name="first_name" required>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="last_name">Surname</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="Last name" name="last_name">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="inputEmail">Email *</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="you@example.com"  name="email" required>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="telephone">Mobile</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Mobile" placeholder="Phone number" name="telephone">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="exampleTextarea" name="comments"></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="6" name="comments" placeholder="What is your enquiry?" required></textarea>

            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>   
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>

    <?php
    //if "email" variable is filled out, send email
      if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

      //Email information
        $admin_email = "#######@gmail.com";
        $first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_REQUEST['last_name'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $telephone = $_REQUEST['telephone'];
        $comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];

      //send email
      mail($admin_email, "$first_name", $last_name, "$telephone", "$comments", "From:" . $email);

      //Email response
      echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
      }

      //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
      else  {
    ?>

    <?php
      }
    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can't have nested form tags. Use only one.

Comment: two form open tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
  <form name="enquiryform" method="post" action="">
        <h2>Contact us!</h2>

<form class="form-horizontal">
```

to

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="enquiryform" method="post" action="#">
        <h2>Contact us!</h2>
```

Comment: in action try $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  if you fail

Comment: Thanks Mudassar, that worked. Really appreciate it! New problem is it isn't sending the enquiry through to my email.. ideas?

Comment: @Natalie 1 question per SO question. [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) please.

Comment: Sure @ʰᵈˑ, sorry!